# Getting Error while Updating UserProfile using Docusign admin api [docusignapi]

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I want to update user profile (**Federated_status**), using DocuSign Admin Api.

Below are the scopes specified in the URL to generate the login UI using Auth Code Grant
 (signature organization_read group_read user_read user_write).

But when I call the Docusing admin api using below code, it doesn't allow any update and throws error "unauthorized"

```
try
            {
                HttpContent PostContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ObjUser), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                string reponsebody = string.Empty;
                string Url = "https://api-d.docusign.net/management/v2/organisation/" + OrgID + "users/profiles";
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application / json"));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token));
                    HttpResponseMessage rep = client.PostAsync(new System.Uri(Url), PostContent).Result;
                    reponsebody = rep.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
                var userProfileResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfile>(reponsebody);
                return userProfileResponse;
            }
```

further to it

1. I have included all roles (See URL Below used for auth code grant)

https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20organization_read%20group_read%20user_read%20user_write&client_id=4c1exxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost50455

2. when i pasted the above url in browser- I got that obtaining consent below roles only:
   a. Read domain details of the organization.
   b. Read identity Provider details of the organization.
   c. Read List of permission sets of an account.
   d. Read Account details.

   - I don't see any user related permission there. i am not sure why, but you can see i have add all the scopes related to users (user_read user_write) to that URL.

Any suggestions

I am still getting error : 400 - "unauthorized" while updating the user profile.

Comment: how did you obtain the access token? You may need to ensure you have the require scope and/or admin consent.

Comment: Below are steps that i performed to generate access token. 1. Get integration Key, Secret Key and set Redirect Url in tha admin panel --> APIs and key section. 2. Then I have taken Authorization code grant url from the DocuSign portal and I have setted the  required scope , integration Key and secret key with base 64 format with redirect url and I have hitted the url in browser 3. Provided the consent for read/ user-write. 4. Which in return code and j have called the OAuth api by passing parameters of code , integration Key and secret key OAuth return the token response.

Comment: ok, the URL you used for Auth Code Grant, (the one with https://account-d.docusign.com/) had some scopes information. Did it just have &scope=signature? I think that may be the issue

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/orgadmin-api/guides/auth see list of scopes and see if you used the right one

Comment: I have the same list of scopes to be specific I have used user_write user_read organization_read.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue has to do with the proper scopes that you specific in the URL you used for Auth Code Grant. (that is the account-d URL)

[Check list of scopes](https://developers.docusign.com/orgadmin-api/guides/auth)

Ensure that the &scope parameter in the URL has the right scopes you need for this endpint.

Comment: Moreover the admin permission consent also shows that user write , update to accept after which returns token for me . Which is use to call to update profile .

Comment: just to rule it out - can you add ALL scopes in the list I sent. If you still get the error - it's not a scope issue.

Comment: included all roles https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20organization_read%20group_read%20user_read%20user_write&client_id=4c1exxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost50455
to test the above url in browser- it show obtaining consent for below roles only. Read domain details of the organization. Read identity Provider details of the organization. Read List of permission sets of an account.Read Account details.I don't see any user related permission there. i am not sure why,I have add all the scopes related to users (user_read user_write).

Comment: For better understanding I have updated the Question.

Comment: do you have an organization created? with a domain etc? I think this particular activity requires one.

Comment: Yes, we have organisation with domain.

Comment: I actually don't see all scopes in your URL, for example "identity_provider_read" is not in the list. Can you add the entire list, even if you don't think it's needed, just to see if it fixes it or not?

Comment: I added that too and tried one more time, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Anvit, this issue requires a deeper look from our engineers etc. You will need to work with our customer support dept to understand it. Let me know if you want my help to facilitate it.